# How can I assign value to specific vector's index?

Tags: c++, vector

```
In header file...

    public:
    struct storeData
        {
            int iAccountNumber;
            int iPin;
            double dBalance;
            string sFirstName;
            string sLastName;
            string sMiddleInitial;
        };
        vector <storeData> storeDataArray;

private:
    string sTempArray [7];

    string m_sFirstName;
    string m_sLastName;
    string m_sMiddleInitial;
    int m_iAccountNumber;
    int m_iPin;
    double m_dAmount;
```

---

IN another file (.cpp)

---

m_iAccountNumber = atoi(sTempArray[1].c_str()); //account number info is located in index 1
    m_sFirstName = atoi(sTempArray[2].c_str()); //first name is located in index 2
    m_sLastName = atoi(sTempArray[3].c_str()); //last name is located in index 3
    m_sMiddleInitial = atoi(sTempArray[4].c_str()); //middle inital is located in index 4
    m_dAmount = atoi(sTempArray[5].c_str()); //amount is located in index 5
    m_iPin = atoi(sTempArray[6].c_str()); // pin info is located in index 6
cout << "AFTER assign variable from array"<< endl;
    //int iAccountFinder = findAccountNumberInStore(m_iAccountNumber); //send data to function to validate if account number is exist or not

```
int iIndex = 0;

while(!storeDataArray.empty())//index could be 0 if array is empty or find that array is not empty and use loop until empty
{
    if(m_iAccountNumber == storeDataArray[iIndex].iAccountNumber)
    {
        //return error code DU (duplication account number)
    }
    iIndex ++; //to keep loop until empty index
}
if(m_dAmount <= 0)
{
    //return error code BADAMT
}
```

THE code in below caused program to crashed.

```
storeDataArray[iIndex].iAccountNumber = m_iAccountNumber;
storeDataArray[iIndex].sFirstName = m_sFirstName;
storeDataArray[iIndex].sLastName = m_sLastName;
storeDataArray[iIndex].sMiddleInitial = m_sMiddleInitial;
storeDataArray[iIndex].dBalance = m_dAmount;
storeDataArray[iIndex].iPin = m_iPin;
```

Comment: Are you ever removing elements from `storeDataArray`? Why do you expect it to eventually be empty?

Comment: never use `using` clauses in header files.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you should use a function to create a data to be stored in an entry of you vector:

```
storeData makeStoreData(int accountNumber, int pin, double balance, const string& fn, const string& ln, const string& mi) {
    storeData data;
    data.iAccountNumber = accountNumber
        data.iPin = pin;
    data.dBalance = balance;
    data.sFirstName = fn;
    data.sLastName = ln;
    data.sMiddleInitial = mi;
}
```

Then add successive elements using [`std::vector::push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/):

```
storeDataArray.push_back(makeStoreData(m_iAccountNumber, m_iPin, m_dAmount, m_sFirstName, m_sLastName, m_sMiddleInitial));
```

You can also use [`std::vector::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) but be aware of these facts:

> The vector is extended by inserting new elements before the element at
>   the specified position, effectively increasing the container size by
>   the number of elements inserted.
>
> This causes an automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space
>   if -and only if- the new vector size surpasses the current vector
>   capacity.
>
> Because vectors use an array as their underlying storage, inserting
>   elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container
>   to relocate all the elements that were after position to their new
>   positions. This is generally an inefficient operation compared to the
>   one performed for the same operation by other kinds of sequence
>   containers (such as list or forward_list).